# Batch file to loop through subfolder and use subfolder name as variable

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file, subdirectory

this is my first post as im having a little trouble with a batch file to loop through subfolders and use the subfolder name as a variable in a command. I have managed to get the code well enough advanced and it runs, but continually repeats running with the last folder name in the main directory. It doesn't find and cycle through the other subfolders.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET MYPATH=H:\RAWBDA\001076\host

for /d %%a in (%mypath%\*) do set "folderName=%%a"
echo %folderName%

for /d %%f in (%folderName%) do set myfolder=%%~nxf
echo %myfolder%

FOR /d /r %%i IN ('DIR /B %mypath%*.tif') DO (

trial.exe "%foldername%\%myfolder%_B4.tif" "%foldername%\%myfolder%_B3.tif" "%foldername%\%myfolder%_B2.tif" "%foldername%\%myfolder%_B432.tif"

)
```

I beleive the problem is that the FolderName and myFolder are outside the loop, but i cant get them to dynamically update within the loop.

Very grateful for some help.

Comment: The subfolders all have the same length of characters

    LT50010762006058COA00

There are typically 10 - 50 in the main directory (H:\RAWBDA\001076\host)

The desired command line for the trial utility, would be as follows for the first subfolder

`trial.exe "H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B4.tif" "H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B3.tif" "H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B2.tif" "H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B432.tif"`

Comment: There are approx 10 `.tif` files in each subfolder. However, if you notice in my code i select the order manually (_B4, _B3, B2 and _B432), so `trial` can run with the correct `.tif`

Comment: It wont let me edit the original item. I think its because its my first post.

Good point with the %%i. My batch skills are beginner and i copy things from other scripts. any ideas how to fix this with the nested loop

Comment: The same as above>

`"H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B4.tif" "H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B3.tif" "H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\LT50010762006058COA00\LT50010762006058COA00_B2.tif" `

The name of the .tif files are the folder name with the _BX, where X varies from 1 to 9

Comment: Ok, i have this folder

H:\RAWBDA\001076\host\

In this folder are subfolder that have a unique code. for example, the first folder is LT50010762006058COA00.

In each folder are .tif files, all named "subfoldername_BX.tif", where X varies from 1 to 9.

To run the trial command, i just have to cycle through each subfolder and select images B4, B3 and B2. The last line B432 is a file to combine  the three .tif files. This is the output of trial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is simple: enumerate the subfolders and to get their names use a prefix `%%~nx`:

```
SET "MYPATH=H:\RAWBDA\001076\host"
rem Using quotes around "var=value" in case the path may contain spaces

for /d %%a in ("%mypath%\*") do (
    echo Folder name: %%~nxa, full folder path: %%a
    trial.exe "%%a\%%~nxa_B4.tif" "%%a\%%~nxa_B3.tif" "%%a\%%~nxa_B2.tif" "%%a\%%~nxa_B432.tif"
)
```